# How to get all rows from a table in Firebase synchronously?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, synchronous

Consider below snippet of code:

```
public ArrayList<GenericModel> getList(GenericModel model) {
    ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ArrayList<GenericModel> genericModels = new ArrayList<>();

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                GenericModel genericModel = postSnapshot.getValue(model.getClass());
                genericModels.add(genericModel);
            }
            Collections.sort(genericModels, (o1, o2) -> o1.getDate().compareTo(o2.getDate()));

            return genericModels;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            return null;
        }
    };
    mDatabase.child(model.getTableName()).child(mUser.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(postListener);
}
```

Right now this code doesn't work, I can only solve this by a callback. And I don't want that. I want a method returning an ArrayList. How could I rewrite this? Using Kotlin is also an option.

Comment: Post a screenshot of your database!

Comment: Dear Rahul, the problem is how to reprogram it using a method returning ArrayList<GenericModel>. The code was working fine with a callback. You want me to post the callback code?

Comment: I will post my code for retrieving all the rows

Comment: Firebase APIs are not designed to work synchronously.  You should be using asynchronous programming to deal with it.  Bear in mind also that blocking the main thread of your app is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

In this code I am retrieving all the rows available in that node:

//Global Variable \
ArrayList arrayListEventName = new ArrayList();

```
public ArrayList<String or Pojo>getEventNames() {
        progressDialog();
        //----Shared Preference----\\
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        String emailId = prefs.getString(StaticValues.PREF_EMAIL, "name@provider,com");
        emailId = emailId.replace(".", ",");
        //--------------\\

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(); // Database Instance \\
        DatabaseReference databaseReference_users = database.getReference("admin").child(emailId)
                .child("eventsCreated");
        databaseReference_users.addValueEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(final com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                arrayListEventName.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String eventName = (String) postSnapshot.child("eventName").getValue(String.class).toLowerCase();
//                    if(eventName.equals(eventName2)){
//
//                    }
                    arrayListEventName.add(eventName);
                }

                dismissDialog();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
```

return arrayListEventName;

```
    }
```

Screenshot:

[image: Database Screenshot]

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem because I need a method returning an ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

```
public Task<ArrayList<GenericModel>> getList(GenericModel model) {
    if (!mIsInitialized) {
        initialize();
    }

    final TaskCompletionSource<ArrayList<GenericModel>> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<>();

    if (mIsInitialized) {
        ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                ArrayList<GenericModel> genericModels = new ArrayList<>();

                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    GenericModel genericModel = postSnapshot.getValue(model.getClass());
                    genericModels.add(genericModel);
                }
                Collections.sort(genericModels, (o1, o2) -> o1.getDate().compareTo(o2.getDate()));

                tcs.setResult(genericModels);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                tcs.setResult(null);
            }
        };

        mDatabase.child(model.getTableName()).child(mUser.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(postListener);

    }
    return tcs.getTask();
}
```

And here the calling method: (Kotlin, with co-routines)

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    doAsync {
        val task = FirebaseManager.getInstance().getList(FixedCosts())
        task.addOnCompleteListener {
            uiThread {
                if (task.result != null) {
                    //show the result in UI 
                }
          }
      }
}
```